# Struts 2.0 request getparameter values to Bean object

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have a jsp page having form of employee details as below.

AddEmp.jsp

```
<th>First Name :</th>
<td><input type = "text" id ="firstName" name = "firstName" value= ""></td>
<th>Middle Name :</th>
<td><input type = "text" id ="middleName" name = "middleName" value= ""></td>
<th>Last Name :</th>
<td><input type = "text" id ="lastName" name = "lastName" value= ""></td>
```

After Submit the form i got the values in the controller

```
public class contTest extends ActionSupport{
  public String firstName;
  public String lastName;
  public String execute(){
    System.out.println("firstName-->>>"+firstName);
    System.out.println("lastName-->>>"+lastName);
    return SUCCESS;
  }
}
```

The Struts 2.0 automatically set the values(defined as Public) and can able to access it.

My question is --!! i have a DAO of Employee having all the details like below.

```
 public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable{
     public String firstName;
     public String lastName;

    public String getFirstName(){
     return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName){
     this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName(){
     return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName){
     this.lastName = lastName;
    }
 }
```

Once my HTML form submits from the JSP i want all the fields to be set to the DAO and will directly call the DAO inside the controller instead manually defined each fields in the controller. Can Anybody help on this.? Thx in advance.

P.S : i am new to struts 2.0.

**Update 1 :** 
Thanks Guys For your response. And i am Jealous on your Knowledge.

I tried [msr](/questions/tagged/msr) way and thats what the result i exactly want.
I accept [msr](/questions/tagged/msr) reply as the Answer.
[msr](/questions/tagged/msr) can u please tell the name of the concept we implemented and i like to learn and knew the benefits of the ModelDriven Logic suggested by our friend [alexander](/questions/tagged/alexander).

Can any one pls elaborate with some simple example?

Comment: Wow my misspelled name in the tag. I didn't suggested to use modeldriven.

Comment: @AleksandrM : i have a question , can't we use model driven for it?

Comment: @abhijeet: Can doesn't mean we should.

Comment: @AleksandrM i got it :) but is't that a better way of doing that if bean class have many attributes ?

Comment: @abhijeet: How that changes anything?

Comment: @AleksandrM that does't change anything but that probably removes those repetetive getters setters from your code. probably that's why they featured that concept. Is there any other use of it .Please let me know if i am not aware of it?

Comment: @abhijeet: What kind of repetitive getters are you talking about?

Comment: @AleksandrM `Wow my misspelled name in the tag. I didn't suggested to use modeldriven.` I laughed *hard* :D And we know you always suggest ModelDriven.

Comment: @AndreaLigios: :D Never seen a name in the tag before. Kind of cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class contTest extends ActionSupport{
  public Employee  emp1;
  public String execute(){
    System.out.println("firstName-->>>"+emp1.getFirstName());
    System.out.println("lastName-->>>"+emp1.getLastName());
    return SUCCESS;
  }

  //Create Setter and Getter of emp1 object
}
```

and in AddEmp.jsp

```
<th>First Name :</th>
<td><input type = "text" id ="firstName" name = "emp1.firstName" value= ""></td>

<th>Last Name :</th>
<td><input type = "text" id ="lastName" name = "emp1.lastName" value= ""></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement Model ModelDriven interface to your action class.which has method  getModel() method to return the Employee’s object. Refer this link : http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/model-driven.html

When using the ModelDriven method you need to initialize the Model object((Employee)) , so the framework will automatically transfers the form data into the Employee class

Comment: Noooo. Not the modeldriven interface.

Comment: Is't model driven interface is for the same purpose?? Link:http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/model-driven.html

Comment: Don't mess with modeldriven unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: His requirement is what model driven interface does.

Comment: And again NO. OP is new to S2 so MSR answer better fits. Can you justify usage of modeldriven?

Comment: What @shankar has asked that he directly want to set value to dao's object , so  i think that he don't want to create those extra getters and setters in his action class which  already he has created in Employee class that way it will work but  right approach will be using model driven interceptor for  it.

Comment: @abhijeet Thanks friend for your reply. I got the answer but like to know the Logic and uses of the ModelDrive . can u explain or suggest me some ?

Comment: Modal driven interface is used when you don't want redundency , as in your action class you had to create getters and setters because param interceptor which sets values  from form to your attributes looks for getters and setters in value stack , so by modal interceptor(means by implement model driven interface and using getmodel()) you pushes object of your bean class directly into  value stack , so you  don't require to create those getters and setters in your action class. that's it :)

Comment: @abhijeet can u please update my above example with ModalDriven Implementation ?!