# struts2+ Set Form value to POJO and Set POJO Value To form

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, struts2

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305803/struts-2-0-request-getparameter-values-to-bean-object) you made me clear how to deal with JAVA objects in Struts ;

JSP

```xml
<th>First Name :</th>
<td><input type="text" id ="em.firstName" name="em.firstName" value=""></td>
<th>Middle Name :</th>
<td><input type="text" id ="em.middleName" name="em.middleName" value=""></td>
<th>Last Name :</th>
<td><input type="text" id ="em.lastName" name="em.lastName" value=""></td>
```

Action Class

```java
public class contTest extends ActionSupport{
  public Employee  em;
  public String execute(){
    System.out.println("firstName-->>>"+em.getFirstName());
    System.out.println("lastName-->>>"+em.getLastName());
    return SUCCESS;
  }

  //Setter and Getter of em object
}
```

Now I would like to use the same JSP where I fetch data from database (and fit the values back to the form using the employee Object) for update too.

How can I map the em.firstName with the Object firstName variable ?

**Edit 1 :**

Edited ...

**Update 3 : **

Hope will clear it now.

**First i select the employee and click Go button.**

```
$('#Go').click(function(){
    if($("#txtEmpId").val() == "" || $("#txtEmpId_name").val()==""){
        alert("Please Select Employee.");
        return false;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'EmpView.action',
        data: $("#FrmEmp").serialize(),
    }).done(function(data) {
        $("#FrmEmp").submit();
    });
    $('#EmployeeDet,#divEmpId').show();
});
```

**Struts.xml**

```
<action name="EmpView" class="com.Test.Controller.EmpCntr" method= "EmpView">
    /*I tried with Both*/
    <result name = "success" type="json"/>

    or

    <result name="success">/AddEmp.jsp</result>
</action>
```

**Action Class :**

```
public String EmpView() throws SQLException, IOException{
    System.out.println("em.firstName--->>>"+em.getFirstName());
    System.out.println("em.lastName--->>>"+em.getLastName());
    try {
        CachedRowset tmList = TmMo.GetEmpViewData(ProcName,ParaName);

        int numcols = tmList.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        List <String> row = new ArrayList<>(numcols);
        while (tmList.next()) {
            for (int i=1; i<= numcols; i++) {
                row.add(tmList.getString(i));
                em.setEmployeeId(tmList.getString("employeeId"));
                em.setFirstName(tmList.getString("firstName"));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("em.firstName--->>>"+em.getFirstName());
        System.out.println("em.lastName--->>>"+em.getLastName());
        /*Here i am getting the Name */
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Action.SUCCESS;
}
```

**AddEmp.jsp**

**Go Button :**

```
<td>
<button type = "button" name = "Go" id= "Go">Go</button>
<button type = "button" name = "Add" id= "Add">Add Employee</button>
</td>
```

**Form Fields:**

```
<th>First Name :</th>
<td><input type = "text" id ="em.firstName" name = "em.firstName" value = "<s:property value='em.firstName'/>" ></td>           
    or 
<s:textfield id ="em.firstName" name = "em.firstName"/>
```

i tried both the ways and clear the path on what i want to do. removed all the unwanted things and Put the sample code only and try with the Sample one only. Its not working!! can i cleared u ?? can u help me where i missed ??

Comment: Please, stop using [tag:] to call people in your question description... 1) it's not working, 2) it's wrong, 3) it's ugly and 4) it's useless

Comment: Ya sure.. wont do that next time. And u don know the answer rite ?

Comment: You don't have any jQuery here. Your object is `emp` not `em`.

Comment: do u mean when webpage load it getdata from DB or when u click submit button it will get data from DataBase and again load same page ?

Comment: i am using the submit button for adding the form to the database. For update i want to select the employee id and get the data from database to employee Object and from object to HTML form (Without reload if possible via ajax). i can set the employee object from database. But How can i set back to the HTML ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you are asking how to map the properties between two objects, one coming from the page, the other from the database, let's say `Employee` and `EmployeeDto`, you can use [Apache Commons `BeanUtils.CopyProperties(target,source)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29).

It will copy all the properties from the source object to the target object matching them by name.

EDIT:

Since you have only one object, it is already mapped. Simply remove `value=""` from all your tags.

Also note that your object must be called `em` or `emp` in both Action class and JSP, while now they're `emp` and `em`, hence not matching... and remember to put getters, setters and a default no args constructor for your Employee object too.

Finally, do not use Struts 2.0 that is from 2008, use Struts 2.3.16.x or above.

EDIT 2:

Oh dear. Didn't noticed you was using standard inputs... Use `<s:textfield />` tag instead:

```xml
<s:textfield name="em.firstName"  />
<s:textfield name="em.middleName" />
<s:textfield name="em.lastName"   />
```

Or without using struts tags, with  tag in value:

```xml
<input type="text" name="em.firstName"  value="<s:property value='em.firstName'/>"  />
<input type="text" name="em.middleName" value="<s:property value='em.middleName'/>" />
<input type="text" name="em.lastName"   value="<s:property value='em.lastName'/>"   />
```

Comment: But i dont have 2 object's, I have a JSP page of HTML form, for add i used the above logic. I just want the same to show existing data, Means i retrieve the data from the Database and get it inside the Employee object then i want to show the values in the JSP. Here my name and ID properties are all starts with "em.". How can i map it.?

Comment: Will try it and get back you with the code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am still working on the Add employee form related changes , validations and data flow. Once complete will start the update relate development. Will try to update today or else on Monday only.

Comment: @SankarNadar it's not clear: did it worked and you updated the question to ask a new question ? If yes, please accept this answer that solved your first problem, and open a new question

Comment: Thanks for the response. My Requirement is Setting a form value to POJO and Setting the POJO Object values to Form variable. As the First one was cleared with the POST i had attached. I am looking for the "Setting Values from PoJO Object to Form Variable". Thats y i updated the Question with the new details. and more over the above answer didnt fullfill my requirement i cannot accept it as answer. If u want me to accept and create a new question i can do.

Comment: I set the Employee Object Manually to check whether the POJO values flow to Form Value by.

em.setFirstName("Sankar");
Like that. even though i am not getting the output. i removed the value = "" from the form tag's. and i redirect to the JSP from the action class.

Comment: I don't want you to upvote or accept if it didn't help... was just wondering if it helped or not. Please check out the last edit...

Comment: I cannot use Struts tag as the tags are not seat inside the table as per my design, i need to create some user defined CSShtml for the <S> tag so drop that idea. Currently my flow is select a employee Id from the list and click on Go button. Go button calls a Ajax of action(above empView function) and returns as Action.Success and i tried result type with JSon and redirect directly to the jsp Page also and moreover i am using Jquery validate.js for validating the forms and Submiting. Hope i cleared it well and looking forward for best approach and solution.

Comment: It's not clear at all. I've edited for the last time, to show you how to do it without s:textfield. You need to use s:property btw. If you can't use ANY struts tag, then why are you using Struts 2 ? Also the bunch of technologies and techniques you are using only adds complexity, not clarity... I **strongly** suggest you to proceed step by step, with small running examples at first, included in bigger pages / actions / projects later. Like this is a continuous jump in the dark. KISS paradigm FTW.

Comment: Please check my new Update.!!

Comment: Sorry, I can't. It will lead to another update, then another, then... please, restart from scratch, maybe following a tutorial from a site that is not 2008 and not roseindia :) What you are asking is very basic, the fact that it's not working is mainly due to the overcomplexity in your code / patterns / work methodology. The "<result> stuff" clearly shows it (*I've tried with both apples and bananas in the dark...*). One step at a time is the only solution here

Comment: @AndreaLigios: Last comment should be one of the closing reasons. ;)

Comment: Yup Sure.. That's why i accept the suggestions as Answer. That Guy Guide properly.

Comment: Romeo: glad that you worked it out, thanks for accepting. @AleksandrM : I think I have lost you :) ?

Comment: @AndreaLigios: I mean your comment is good candidate to the list of closing reasons between `unclear what you're asking` and `too broad`. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Solved :**

I create an Employee DAO object and assign the DAO for Action Class Getter ,Setter Employee Object Variable.

Here my latest code.

```
public String EmpView() throws SQLException, IOException{
    System.out.println("em.firstName--->>>"+em.getFirstName());
    System.out.println("em.lastName--->>>"+em.getLastName());
    try {
        CachedRowset tmList = TmMo.GetEmpViewData(ProcName,ParaName);

        while (tmList.next()) {
            for (int i=1; i<= numcols; i++) {
                Employee emp = new Employee();
                emp.setEmployeeId(tmList.getString("employeeId"));
                emp.setFirstName(tmList.getString("firstName"));
                em = emp;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("em.firstName--->>>"+em.getFirstName());
        System.out.println("em.lastName--->>>"+em.getLastName());
        /*Here i am getting the Name */
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Action.SUCCESS;
}
```

And i am getting the value's in the HTML forms. I am using the same page for both add and Edit the Employee Details.

As suggested by Andrea i had removed the HTML standards and Use Struts tags and accepting Andrea reply as Answer.

Thanks alot.